# SQL dependency fires many times

Tags: c#, sqldependency

SQL dependency fires many times. The first time I open the main form it works perfectly, but when I enter a form and get back to the main one it fires twice, when I enter another time to a form it will fire three times and so on.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    public string connectionstring = "my connection string";

    public Form1()
    {           
        SqlDependency.stop(connectionstring);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionstring);
        InitializeComponent();      
        not();       
    }

    public void not()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id,noofflight, pnr, details FROM dbo.tbl_fls;";
        cmd.Notification = null;

        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        dependency.OnChange -= new

        OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);  //unsubscribe the old event

        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);// //subscribe new event

        SqlDataReader a = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (a.Read())
        {
            // Doing something here...
        }           

        con.Close();
    }

    public void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "there is a change ";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(15000);
            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Warning;
            //notify the user               
        }
        //do nothing!! 
    }

    not();
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions?!!

Comment: Since you create a new `SqlDependency` in every call, trying to "unsubscribe" does nothing. The old dependency is still hanging around firing off events.

Comment: so how i could remove the old event?

Comment: I suggest keeping only one `SqlDependency` around instead of creating a new one every time. You could wrap the whole SQL logic up in its own little class and keep a `static` instance of that (and possibly create it in the `Program`, rather than tying it to a `Form` instance).